# Submitting Form with url as Field Value

Tags: php, html, forms

So i am having some trouble with submitting form that contains url as an input value. Below is the code, the value and the error message. can anyone please advise?

**My Form**

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

[Value of Input{Name}]
http://www.company.com

When i submit the form i get the error below:

> **Forbidden**
> You don't have permission to access /devadmin/panel/test.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: question is: "how" are you accessing this, as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? I'm thinking the latter. There's also no php here and what is the file extension?

Comment: I am not working on a local machine therefore not using localhost what i have is a form and an url value to the input field... when ever i try submitting it on my live server, i get a 403 error!!!

Comment: there; you need to run this off a webserver with php installed. You can't just run this off like a regular html page.

Comment: i have figured it out... my server dont accept http:// or https:// in a textfield so i wrote a jquery function

Comment: Great, glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

i have figured it out... my server dont accept http:// or https:// in a textfield so i wrote a jquery function

```
function remove_http(){
     $('input[type="text"]').on('focusout',function(e){
        vals = $(this).val()
        if(vals.includes('http://')){
            value = vals.split('http://')
            $(this).val('www.'+value[1])
        }
        if(vals.includes('https://')){
            value = vals.split('https://')
            $(this).val('www.'+value[1])
        }
        if(vals.includes('http://www.')){
            value = vals.split('http://www.')
            $(this).val('www.'+value[1])
        }
        if(vals.includes('https://www.')){
            value = vals.split('https://www.')
            $(this).val('www.'+value[1])
        }
      })
    }
    remove_http()
```

this remove http or https from the link in the textfield.